# Help needed identifying this 180 degree bottom insertion ffc connector and how to release the cable

Tags: identification, connector, ribbon-cable, fpc, ffc

I could not see any hinge or flap or other release mechanism. The connector seems like it is one piece of plastic with no obvious seams although in some images I think tooling marks look a bit like seams. I couldn't pull the cable out with moderate force.

I believe this is the cable that is associated with the connector. It does not appear as though the notch goes inside the connector.

[image]

Then just a lot of different views:

The cable comes through a slot in the PCB up into the connector. The connector has through-hole pins on the side nearest the black relays (opposite the PCB edge)
*Note the small plastic spur sticking up is from me prying on the connector and not physical feature.
[image]

No obvious flange/door or release tabs.
[image]

Looks like a single piece of plastic.
[image]

Prying on this back slot did not seem do anything
[image]

[image]

Looks like it just goes straight in with the contacts:
[image]

Comment: Two theories, although I'm not familiar with this:  (1) The white casing may move sideways or pop up when pulled gently to release the cable, or (2) it's a friction fit and may come out with gentle pressure.  Good luck, and don't use too much force!

Comment: According to this [yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzuMxjyHxx8) you can just pull the cable out.

Comment: @funkyeah Do you have a pitch on that connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a friction fit. The thickness of the stiffener on the flex PCB suggests that the board edge connector is actually a 180deg card edge connector, which also suggests friction fit. The size looks like it's for a 20-30mil FR4 stiffener (be nice to check the thickness).

The notch (enforced by the PCB) ensures that the connector is keyed.

This looks like an older/chinese connector or a custom connector, it's not one made by  a manufacturer. You might be able to match the pitch and the card thickness with a different connector but it wouldn't be a 180deg connector.

Comment: From [Poke-in LIF FFC/FPC sockets](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NP&n=ffc_fpc_lif_sockets) on [Davide Andrea's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/49808/davide-andrea) Identiconn™ think the term might be a _Poke-in_ FFC socket. However, can't seem to find a range which matches the picture in the question.

Comment: I need to get his book... Its not an FPC connector at least not a new one...